# Baked normal map partially inside out (Blender/Unity)

Tags: baking, unity, normal-map

I'm baking a normal map using a high-poly mesh and a low-poly mesh. Things seem to work out, except some UV-islands are... inside out?

In unity it looks like this:

[image: positive normals] [image: negative normals]

The left image has normal map strength set to 2.0 (exaggerated for clarity) while the right image has normal map strength -2.0

As you can see, in the left image the left wing is inside-out while the right wing is correct. In the right image it's vice versa.

[image: angelBlender]

I have tried normal recalculating, flipping etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[image: mirrored uvs]

So apparently a thing that can happen is that the unwrap algorithm puts down some islands mirrored. A way to see this is to view the model with the grid texture and look for flipped letters/numbers.

Hope that helps someone out there!